# How to avoid typescript errors in ionic2 application?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Hi I am Working With `Ionic2`.Here I got some errors while using `JSON.parse(this.items1)` Actually that is not an error in `Javascript` but it shows error in ts file ... How to avoid these errors?

**Error**

```
 TypeScript error: E:/Projects 2016/TaskBean/mytaskbeanapp/app/pages/list/list.ts
(38,21): Error TS2345: Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter o
f type 'string'.
10.3 MB bytes written (2.13 seconds)
```

**Code**

```
import {Component,Type} from '@angular/core';
import {ModalController, NavController, NavParams,MenuController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ItemDetailsPage} from '../item-details/item-details'; 
import {AddItemPage} from '../addtask/add';
import {ItemDetailPage} from '../item-detail/item-detail';
import {Data} from '../providers/data';
import {Http, Response, Headers, Request, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, URLSearchParams} from 
'@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/list/list.html',
})
export class ListPage  extends Type {

 selectedItem: any;
  private items = [];
  private items1 = [];
   result: Object;
    public mydata = [];

   projectid:string;
  constructor(private nav: NavController, navParams: NavParams,public menu:MenuController,private dataService: Data, private modalCtrl: ModalController,public http:Http) {
   this.result = {friends:[]};



      http.get('http://192.168.0.26:9000/api/task/counttask?projectid=-1&Teamid=-1&RoleId=-1&status=1&PID=-1&mytasks=0&alltasks=0&page=1&row=15&priorityid=-1&typeid=-1&taskname=&JSON&_=1471520478215')

    .map((res: Response) => res.json())

.subscribe(

                  res => { this.items1 = res;
            **alert(JSON.parse(this.items1))**
try
{

    alert(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(this.items1).Data));


    window.localStorage['mydata']=this.items;


    }
    catch(e)
    {

    }





         },

        () => console.log('getUserStatus Complete') // complete
    );



 this.selectedItem = navParams.get('item');
 this.menu.enable(true, 'mymenu');
 this.dataService.getData().then((todos) => {



        if(todos){
            this.items = JSON.parse(todos); 
        }

    });

  }
  itemTapped(event, item) {

    this.nav.push(ItemDetailsPage, {
      item: item
    });
  }
  addItem(){

    let addModal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddItemPage);

    addModal.onDidDismiss((item) => {

      if(item){
        this.saveItem(item);
      }

    });

    addModal.present();

  }

  saveItem(item){
    this.items.push(item);
    this.dataService.save(this.items);
  }

  viewItem(item){
    this.nav.push(ItemDetailPage, {
      item: item
    });
  }

  removeItem(item){

    for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {

      if(this.items[i] == item){
        this.items.splice(i, 1);
                              }

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'string'

The reason you're getting that error just in **Type**script is because `items1` is of type *any[]* and you're assigning it a *string* (`this.items1 = res`).

It's not an error in execution time, because you can assign what ever you want to a variable in JS and it won't complain about it as far as the methods you invoke or the things you do with it don't throw an exception.

To avoid issues like that one, try to *explicitly* declare the types of the properties you're using in your code

```
private items: Array<any> = []; // Instead of any you can declare even how the objects inside the array are
```

And keep in mind **types** when assigning values to them

```
this.items1 = JSON.parse(res); // Instead of this.items1 = res;
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot @sebaferreras Its Working

Comment: Np, glad I could help :)